# Send ZPL code from a PLC through serial port

Tags: printing, ascii, plc, zpl

I have a `Directlogics PLC` that I need to send label information to a `Zebra GC420T printer`.

I can only send ASCII characters. Is it possible to send a file of ASCII characters of a `ZPL` code and if so,

any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: ZPL *is* all-ASCII. Please say what your label contains that apparently *isn't* ASCII and hence is causing you problems. Examples demonstrate the problem best.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Start by matching the serial communications between your PLC and the printer.  Either change the settings on the PLC to match the printer or the printer settings to match the PLC.

Default Zebra settings should be: 9600 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity, and XON/XOFF. PROTOCOL should be set to NONE.

Depending on the way your PLC serial port is pinned, you may need a [null modem cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem).

Try sending the following ZPL code from your PLC to the printer as a test:

```
^XA
^FO50,50
^B8N,100,Y,N
^FDTEST^FS
^XZ
```